# Lightning Beta - Lightning file locations?

Tags: salesforce1-app, versioning, lightning-apps

Our team is exploring Lightning development and a couple of our requirements are to be able to:

1. Work on a shared code base across multiple orgs
2. Check our code into version control

Currently due to packaging + namespace issues as detailed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53786/salesforce-lightning-packaging), #1 will probably have to wait for the next release. (Side note, I've noticed the access control tag 'extensible="true"' does not allow me to save, is that coming too?). For #2, we've only been able to work in the Developer Console and we can't find the lightning app/component/controller/helper files when downloading the entire project into Eclipse. Only the lightning tabs show up which don't have any of the markup/JS we wrote. Is there a way to download the Lightning Component files to a local workspace?

Thanks

Victor - Dev @ Appiphony

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The current force.com eclipse plugin does not have support for lightning components - they are working on it.

The forceCLI however does have full support for lightning components (force ) and this combined with the sublime-lightning plugin for Sublime 2 or 3 has been how I have been working with lightning for the past few months and the integration into sublime is excellent.

I will post install links etc here in a minute once I get back to my desk.

Comment: The first step of installing and working with the forceCLI http://force-cli.herokuapp.com/ you can do right now while I get the author of sublime-lightning to provide some install/usage instructions for us.

Comment: For the Sublime Plugin, make sure you have Package Control installed. https://sublime.wbond.net/installation Once you have that installed, you can install the Lightning plugin/package by pressing CMD+SHIFT+P and then filtering the list by typing "Install Package". This will bring up a list of packages that you can then filter by typing "Lightning". Click the Lightning entry to install. If you right-click on any folder or file in the left side bar, you will be able to Login to Salesforce using username and password through the CLI.

Comment: You will need to open up the terminal and, using the Force CLI, execute "force fetch aura".  This will pull down all your lightning components and put them in <currentdir>/metadata/aura folder.  Each component will have it's own folder that contains the definitions for that component. To create a new component/event/application right click the aura folder. To create a new controller/stylesheet/renderer/etc for the component, right click the component.

Comment: Both the CLI support and the Sublime plugin are a labor of love and not fully tested and may contain bugs.  They are both open source and I would love to receive any and all pull requests.

Comment: @DaveCarroll it seems like https://force-cli.herokuapp.com is unhappy right now w.r.t. its part of the implementation of "force login". The login command is not completing - seems to get past the sfdc login into my org, asks for permission to access my org and then hangs.

Comment: I was not able to get "force fetch aura" to work, or "force aura get" as the help docs suggest. However, "force fetch -t Aura" did work for me.